# How to find the exact group that matches to defined values?

Tags: mysql, sql

*I simplified the table so it is easier to understand.*

I have a table with groups and a group exists of multiple values. Here is the table:

```
VALUE | GROUP
  A   |   1
  B   |   1
  A   |   2
  C   |   2
  B   |   3
  A   |   4
  B   |   4
  A   |   5
  B   |   5
  C   |   5
```

I want to give values to my query wich I programmatically build and find the exact group that matches to these values.

For example if I give value A and B to my query I want as a result group 1 and 4

```
A  ---------------> null 
A and B ----------> 1 and 4 
A , B and C ------> 5 
B  ---------------> 3 
A and C ----------> 2 
C ----------------> null
```

Comment: What queries have you already tried?

Comment: Please explain the rules. Why is A or C NULL for exmaple.

Comment: @PreetSangha: because there is no group which consists only of `A` or only of `C`.

Comment: are `(value, group)` pairs unique?

Comment: @quassnoi: they are not unique - there can be two groups with the same values

Comment: @Jspr: let me put it this way: can you have a record `(A, 1)` in the table twice?

Comment: @Quassnoi: okay, they are unique, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a query like the following (assuming value,group pairs unique):

```
select `GROUP`
from MyTable
group by `GROUP`
having count(`VALUE`) = count(case when `VALUE` IN ('a','b') then 1 end)
   and count(case when `VALUE` IN ('a','b') then 1 end) = @Count;
```

Where `('a','b')` would be the list of values you are testing for, and `@Count` would be the count of different values in your check set (2 in this case).

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78def/13